# Data Overlapping SQL Server Views

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have made a website using asp.net web forms, through website I am storing data in SQL server, having multiple tables in database, they all are joined and created as a view having relationships also. The problem is when the data is entered through web forms it gets stored at last page but in case if I close the browser in the middle then the data in SQL server(in views) starts overlapping it picks up the previous data on first page where the browser was closed. I have tried using sessions but it doesn't work.

i don't know if its the session problem. I have tried sessiontimeout also but still doesn't work

Expected all data to come in the same table with the same record of the same person not overlapping with previous data where the browser was closed in middle.

Comment: What is your question here exactly?

Comment: You need to show us how you are querering the data that "overlaps" also give examples of what it looks like when it is working and when it fails.

Comment: I recommend to update your question with simplified source code, so your problem will be more clear!

Comment: This is off-topic for multiple reasons. But my guess is that you have assumed (falsely) that rows in a table have a particular order that is magically preserved when you select them.